# Static Clones in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple line of code that instantiate objects but when I run the game the clones don't go to the indicated position and instead stay in the same position has the father object.
When I lock at the clones they have a static position I can't move them

```
Instantiate(object, position, object.transform.localRotation);
```

Comment: Do you instantiate from a prefab or you just want a clone of an actual object? Could you add code sample to your question?

Comment: From a Prefab, and the curious thing is that it only happen with some prefabs

Comment: Can you try ```Instantiate(object, position, Quaternion.identity);```  Then change the position/rotation?

Comment: also could you show how you use this instanciated object?

Comment: Where do you get `position` from?

Comment: I try that already  thank you anyway broh!

Comment: The position should be random

Comment: Random in a certain range sure

Comment: Post your whole script in the question haha

Comment: I really believe that the problem is not in the code it's in the prefab because the code work perfectly with other objects

Comment: Yeah but we can't help if you don't show anything hahaha, dump it in the question in case there's something you missed :)

Comment: @MathieuAuclair broh I can post a picture here?

Comment: Because is not code is something really weird going on with the prefab configuration

Comment: no just cut n paste your code sample in the question, if you add 4 space in front of a line, it become code sample

Comment: do you have a git repo link or somewhere the project is visible?

Comment: you can add links to picture

Comment: Btw you shouldn't use the keyword `object` as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure what's wrong without seeing your complete code but try this;

```
 public GameObject yourPrefabRef;

    public void CreateClones(int cloneCount)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < cloneCount; count ++)
        {
           GameObject clone = Instantiate (yourPrefabRef);
           clone.transform.SetParent (parentTransform);
           clone.transform.localPosition = GetRandomPos();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your GameObject is static, this means you cannot move it. See this for reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html